# Netbeans auto format issue with method parameter indention

Tags: php, netbeans

I'm trying to figure out if i missed (or misused) a configuration setting.

Using autoformat on this piece of code:

```
<?php
class foo {

    public function test() {
        $x = $this->foobar(
            1,
            2
        );
    }

}
```

produces:

```
<?php

class foo {

    public function test() {
        $x = $this->foobar(
                1,
                2
        );
    }

}
```

and i'd like netbeans to stop doing that because apart from that the auto formatting works quite well.

It only happens if there is an assignment on the line with the function call.

Comment: The only difference between the two is that one blank line, correct?

Comment: @Steve: Edited out the line to make it more clear: The difference is the indention of the "1" and "2". It changes the 4 spaces to 8

Comment: What version of Netbeans are you using?

Comment: @jacob Product Version: NetBeans IDE 6.9 (Build 201011082200) - 
Java: 1.6.0_23; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 19.0-b09 - 
System: Windows 7 version 6.1 running on x86;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting 2 continuation indents, one for the assignment and one for the parameter list.
If you insert a break between the assignment and `$this->foobar` it becomes more apparent:

```
class foo {
    public function test() {
        $x =
            $this->foobar(
                1,
                2
        );
    }
}
```

So, that's the "why" of it. Unfortunately, NB exposes very few controls for formatting php. There does not appear to be a way to change this behavior.

I'd suggest [opening a bug report](http://netbeans.org/community/issues.html) and keep an eye on the [Netbeans PHP blog](http://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/)

Comment: I wanted to make sure it's not my fault before creating a bug report. Hence the bounty. I'll to that afterwards :)

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the "Continuation Indentation" option to 4.

Go to Tools > Options > Editor. Then select PHP from the Language drop-down and Tabs And Indents from the Category drop-down. The Continuation Indentation option is near the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Saidly that is set to 4 already (and it works for arrays, and it works if there is no assignment on the line with the function call)

Comment: @edorian Darn. Have you tried the options in the Alignment section? Odd that it only does it with assignment.

Comment: I had all those options turned off. Changed it to all on, didn't have any effect. (sorry for the late response, setting a bounty now, if nobody else responds i'll gladly give it to you)