# Netbeans : Auto Format : prevent it for a section of my code

Tags: netbeans, autoformatting

I use Netbeans auto format (ctrl+alt+f) a lot. It's a very nice function!.

But I use StringBuffer.append() to generate some xml. I indent the .append parameter to represente the node structure of my xml.

```
    msg.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
    msg.append(  "<root>");
    msg.append(    "<subNode/>");
```

my problem : the autoformat move all my parameters to the same column.

```
    msg.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
    msg.append("<root>");
    msg.append("<subNode/>");
```

My question : How can I prevent the auto format to to modify my code on a section of my file. I'm hoping to found something similar to "editor-fold".

```
    //<editor-noAutoFormatting>" 
    msg.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
    msg.append(  "<root>");
    msg.append(    "<subNode/>");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question has already been ask :

- [Netbeans: Auto Format - Prevent Space Formatting on Variable Assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7792998/1140748)
- [Netbeans auto format issue with method parameter indention](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5144973/1140748)
- [editing the NetBeans source formatting standard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2712285/1140748)

There is unfortunately  no answer for that. The idea of annotation is not implemented for formatting (or I don't find it).

So from now the only way to avoid this, is to select the text you want to format, *without your xml part* and then use format.

**EDIT** :

The only things I found to avoid autoformat to delete spaces is to use comments `/* */`.The spaces between them will not be trim by Netbeans formatter.

Example :

```
msg.append(/* */"<subNode/>");.
```

Comment: I did saw and read those posts. But my question is different. I do not wish to CHANGE/prevent the GLOBAL autoformat behavior, I want to prevent it ONLY IN A SPECIFIC SECTION Of my code.

Comment: the problem with the "don't select this section of code", is that if you do not select any section, autoformat apply to the whole document!

Comment: The solution I currently use is to add white space in front of my const. (very ugly)

Comment: You're wrong with autoformat, if you select some code then go in Source -> Format (alt+Maj+F in 7.0) it will only format the selected code. And I have understand that you want an option to a "specific section" and I've answer saying that it's not possible sry (I know it's not easy to "read" that the answer is "there is no answer").

Comment: You've thought about the possibility of apply change to "ONLY IN A SPECIFIC SECTION", but do you really think this kind of options can be good? It implied you put some annotations in your code, and I think it's quite ugly to do that for a specific IDE behaviour. You seems to develop in Java so you should know about creating portable application. Adding (let's say) "code" to your app for netbeans is not really following this idea of portability ;)

Comment: Please, reread my comment: if you do NOT select any section, autoformat apply to the whole document!. PS: caps are for polite emphasis, since we cannot format comments.

Comment: "adding some annotations" : yes, it will be specific to NB, but also, the purpose of the annotation is only to change the behavior of NB. PS: the "editor-fold" annotation is perfectly portable.

Comment: Yes, sorry misunderstood about selection. And ok for "editor-fold", it's just I don't like to add code that is not really usefull for the app, but it's only my  point of view. Again sorry to not be able to provide a better answer but I really don't think there is the "feature" you ask in Netbeans (currently).

Comment: no problem. Thanks for your answer/time by the way! I was hoping for some half-hidden/not documented feature of NB to solve this problem. let's see if something come out....

Comment: Ok, I've tried some tricks but I don't found anything concluant... The only things I found is `msg.append(/*    */"<subNode/>");`. But I'm not sure you'll be happy of using this everywhere...

Comment: That a very smart work around ! thanks ! edit your answer, If nobody come with "a real solution", I will accept your answer.

Comment: Ok, I've edited, let's see if someone found something better ;)